# Is is possible to run composer install while suppressing package uninstallation (Drupal 8)?

Tags: php, drupal, composer-php, drupal-8

I'm using Drupal-8, and it requires the following work-flow when a package has been required using composer and installed using Drupal, but is subsequently uninstalled from Drupal and removed via composer by another developer:

1. Update my local repository
2. Run `composer` to install or update (and only install/update) packages in `composer.json`
3. Run scripts in my CMS to deal with package installation/uninstallation details (which depend on the package existence)
4. Run `composer` to uninstall any packages removed from `composer.json`

Step 4 could probably be just `composer install`, but I'm wondering whether there is some way to suppress package uninstallation in Step 2?  Othwerwise, Drupal-8 is unable to complete step 3 because there are Drupal uninstallation instructions embedded in the removed composer package.

Comment: What's the logic behind keeping packages in `vendor` that should no longer be in there, as they are not listed in `composer.json`? That does not make sense to me

Comment: As I stated, in step 3, my CMS (Drupal 8) requires the existence of the package to uninstall the package.  Specifically, this involves removing package artifacts from the system database.

Answer (score 1):

The options for [install](https://getcomposer.org/doc/03-cli.md#install-i) and [update](https://getcomposer.org/doc/03-cli.md#update-u) are right here.

And no, there is no option available to run either command and do only half of its jobs. Removing unneeded dependencies is part of what composer does.

If you want this behaviour, you'll have to code it yourself.

Answer (score 0):

I've tagged this with Drupal, as it may not pertain to other systems.

My solution for now is to capture the deletions in a script that I run after composer install, which re-installes the deleted modules.  Later `git checkout` restores the state of composer.*, then `composer install` runs again.  So the sequence is:

1. Update my local repository
2. Run `composer install` and filter the output to remove ANSI codes and pull out lines starting with " - Removing" followed by lines starting with "Deleting" and reformat them as `composer require` commands in a script called `composer.reinstall.sh`:

```
composer install | tee >(perl -pe 's/\e\[[0-9;]*m//g'|grep -B1 "^Deleting"|grep "^  - Removing"| perl -pe 's/^  - Removing ([^ ]+) \(([^\)]+)\)/composer require \1:\2/g' > composer.reinstall.sh)
```

3. Run the generated script: `sh composer.reinstall.sh`
4. Run scripts in my CMS (`drush cim` and `drush updb` BTW) to deal with package installation/uninstallation details (which depend on the package existence)
5. Reinitialize composer files: `rm composer.reinstall.sh; git checkout composer.*`
6. Run `composer install` to uninstall any packages removed from `composer.json`